# db-shm and db-wal in sqlite databases

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am analyzing some databases that I extract from android devices and I have noticed that some databases are not updated but they are accompanied with two files: .db-shm and .db-wal and these files are updated when I do any changes to the database (while the .db file is not). I understand that these are files used by the database to be able to rollback at anytime. But my question is: Can I apply the changes (or transfer the new data) from .db-wal and .db-shm to the main database (with .db extension)? and how?

Any help is appreciated..Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These databases are using [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

To move the data from the log into the main database file, execute [PRAGMA wal_checkpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) or [PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode).

Answer (score 0):

To move your data from **.db-wal to .db** use  **PRAGMA wal_checkpoint**,
after searching for 2 hours following code worked for me -:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(full)";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int a = cursor.getInt(0);
        int b = cursor.getInt(1);
        int c = cursor.getInt(2);

    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
```